# How does Angular JS load template files under the hood?

Tags: angularjs

I am not asking for tutorial, I want to know technically how is that possible. How is Angular able to load something neither a javascript file nor a style file?

Answer (score 3):

By making an AJAX request to ask the server for this template, and getting it back as a response. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [ngInclude directive source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L208), you'll find this :

```
$http.get(src, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(response) {
```

It just gets the template through ajax like you could do with any file served through HTTP.